# Reverse the order of integration of $\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^\frac{2}{3} \int_{y^2}^{\sqrt y} f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

**Q:** Reverse the order of integration of $\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^\frac{2}{3} \int_{y^2}^{\sqrt y} f(x,y) \, dx\,dy$.

I imagined that $x$ should varie between $\dfrac{1}{9}$ and $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}$ and $y$ varie between $x^2$ and $\sqrt x$, then we get:

$$\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^\frac{2}{3} \int_{y^2}^{\sqrt y} f(x,y) \,dx\,dy = \int_{\frac{1}{9}}^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}} \int_{x^2}^{\sqrt x} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx$$

But that is not the answer cuz i tested it with some $f(x,y)$ and got different values on the integral.

Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: I think the limits of integration are correct.  What are your counter-examples?

Comment: i took $f(x,y) = 1$.

Comment: Did you draw a picture of the region? Because it should be obvious what the limits are if you do.

Comment: yes i drew. what are the limits?

Comment: The limits are incorrect.  Subdivide it into pieces.

Comment: how? any hints?

Comment: The integral you start off with (with $y$ the horizontal coordinate, $x$ the vertical) is computing the area of a vertical strip. If you flip the coordinates $y \leftrightarrow x$ so that $x$ is now the horizontal coordinate and $y$ the vertical, your integration region which was the vertical strip becomes a horizontal strip. To compute the area of this horizontal strip, if you look at the picture, you can see that you need to split your integral up into pieces (as herb referred to above).

Answer (score 1):

Three piece decomposition $\int\limits_\frac{1}{9}^\frac{4}{9}\int\limits_\frac{1}{3}^\sqrt{x}+\int\limits_\frac{4}{9}^\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\int\limits_\frac{1}{3}^\frac{2}{3}+\int\limits_\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}^\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\int\limits_{x^2}^\frac{2}{3}f(x,y)dydx$

Draw a picture.  You will see it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The 'x' limit $y^2$ means $x=y^2$, so we have $y=\sqrt{x}$

The 'x' limit $\sqrt{y}$ means $x=\sqrt{y}$, so we have $y=x^2$

Notice you have exchanged lower and upper 'x' limits

For the 'y' limit $y=\frac{1}{3}$ we must get the $x=y^2 = \frac{1}{9}$ function because $\left(\frac{1}{3} \right)^2 < \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Same reasoning for $y=\frac{2}{3}$ we use the other, $x=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$

Thus, we arrive to
$$\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^\frac{2}{3} \int_{y^2}^{\sqrt y} f(x,y) dxdy= 
\int_{\frac{1}{9}}^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}} \int_{\sqrt x}^{x^2} f(x,y) dydx$$

Being that said, draw both functions (square and root), because perhaps you have to decompose the region into three pieces.

Comment: are you sure? cuz i tried to evaluate the integral with f(x,y) = 1 and got different results in the equality you proposed. Maybe i'm doing something stupid, but i don't see what